# PHP - How can I print out my database table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php code to print out my table including its column name. The printing has to be dynamic because it has to print different size/length tables based on a user input. :

```
<table>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        while ($fieldInfo = mysqli_fetch_field($results)) { ?>
            <th> <?php echo $fieldInfo->name; ?> </th>
            <td> <?php echo $row[$fieldInfo->name] ?> </td>
        <?php } 
    } ?>
</table>
```

this is the query for `$results`:

```
$tName = $_POST["tableNames"];   //this data is recieved from another page
require_once("conn.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tName";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($conn));
```

my code correctly prints out the table name as well as the first row data but it is not formatted correctly here is how it looks:
*[image]*
additionally. for some reason it only prints out the first row even though im using a while loop.

Comment: I would check you example two of the documentation, it doesn't look like you are using it correctly http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Toto my expected result is to print out the whole table including the column names. The printing has to be able to print any table because I pass one of the 5 table name on the database to the page

Comment: while loop comple the end .

Comment: Sure, but you said "it is not formatted correctly", what must be the correct formatting?

Comment: @Toto oh, the formatting is a typical table. like a grid

Comment: @NimeShPatel what do you mean?

Comment: change mysqli_fetch_field to this and use it  mysqli_fetch_array()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice to you is to prepare two arrays:
First one: containing column names and second: containing data.

When use two foreach to generate first row with header and second one to display data. You have forgot to add `<tr>` tags to divide rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use

The `mysqli_fetch_field()` function returns the next column in the result set as an object. It will only returns all column names not the records of table.

You need to use `mysqli_fetch_array()` for getting all records:

```
while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($results,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  {
  echo $info['rid'];
  echo $info['level'];
  ....
  }
```

Comment: the thing is i cant hard code the column name because i need to be able to print any table based on the table name obtained from the a user input. so it can be any of the 5 tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with using a taras' suggestion of storing the column names in an array:

```
<table>
    <?php
    while ($fieldInfo = mysqli_fetch_field($results)) { ?>
        <th> <?php echo $fieldInfo->name; ?> </th>
        <?php 
        $colNames[] = $fieldInfo->name;
        ?>
    <?php } 

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
        <tr>
        <?php for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($colNames); $i++) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $row[$colNames[$i]] ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of my understand, do you want to display all table and their columns?
So you can format like below

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM dbname";
$result_tables = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr><td>Table name</td><td>Fields name</td></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_tables)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";

    $sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$row[0];\\row[0] is used to get table name
    $result_fields = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
    echo "<td>";
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_fields)) {
        echo $row2['Field'].',';
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```